# Passing "not a new" object as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Probably a simple one, I am just learning C#.

I am using VS2013, having two forms.

Goal: A textbox has a default value. At the time of a button (still on form1) is pressed, pass the new, entered value from the textbox on form1, from form1 to form2.

I have one textbox on Form1 and on Form2 a button, that is telling me what's in the textbox of Form1. This is all right, but I am handling TextChangedEvent so if I modify the text, the creation of a new object of Form1 will result in having a new instance, thus the changed text will be wiped out. It remains the default value.

Question: how to reference to the current value of the object, not create a new instance and have default values?

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string value { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.Text = "Default";
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value = this.textBox1.Text;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case -1:
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't choose anything.");
                break;
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("Value of variable: " + value); // Here it's the new value, NOT "Default"
                Form2 form_Form2 = new Form2();
                form_Form2.ShowDialog();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 getdata = new Form1();
        string value = getdata.value;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value: " + value); // Here it's "Default" :(
        }
        else if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value: " + value); // TBD
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a global (ie static) variable?

Comment: Could you show the code please, where you create the instances of Form1 and Form2 (eg in Main).

Comment: Those "two forms, one developer" questions seem to never die...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to inject a reference to `Form1` into `Form2`. You could do this like:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1 OtherForm { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = OtherForm.value;
        ...
```

Then in the sction of code where you create the `Form1` and `Form2` instances, do something like:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.OtherForm = form1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a variable on form 2 and a method that changes it, then when the button is pressed on form 1 do something like form_form2.someMethod(value) 
 but i'm not sure that's the recommended way to handle it.

you would also have to change the scope of form_form2 i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new Form1. Pass your Value to your Form2. I modified your code a little bit:

**Form1**:

```
namespace GUITest
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private string _value = "Default"; // Create a private field with your Default Value

    public string Value
    {
      get
      {
        return _value;
      }
      set
      {
        _value = value
      }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      InitializeComponent();
      this.textBox1.Text = Value;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Value = this.textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      switch (comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
      {
        case -1:
          MessageBox.Show("You didn't choose anything.");
          break;
        case 0:
          MessageBox.Show("Value of variable: " + value); // Here it's the new value, NOT "Default"
          Form2 form_Form2 = new Form2(Value); // Pass the Value to the Constructor of Form2
          form_Form2.ShowDialog();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Form2**

```
namespace GUITest
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {

    private string _value; // Again your field but this time without your default Value

    public Form2(string myVal)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      _value = myVal;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (checkBox1.Checked)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Value: " + _value); // Here it's now not anymore "Default" :)
      }
      else // Removed redundant if
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Value: " + _value); // TBD
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And something general: Even if it's only you who is working on this project... Give your controls self explaining names ;) It'll make your developer life much easier :)

Code should work. I couldn't test it at the moment. If errors occur then pls comment! :)

*Source: My own know-how ^^*

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `ShowDialog()`, simply grab the value off your Form2 instance when it returns execution back to Form1.  Form2 does **not** need any kind of reference to Form1 for this to work...

So you need to do two things:

1. Somehow pass the current value to Form2 (via the Constructor is a common way and has already been shown).
2. Retrieve the new value off Form2 if "OK" was returned.  A property in Form2 would be best.

Here are those two things put together:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.Text = "Default";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case -1:
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't choose anything.");
                break;
            case 0:
                Form2 form_Form2 = new Form2(this.textBox1.Text);
                if (form_Form2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.textBox1.Text = form_Form2.Value;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    private Form2() { }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }

    public Form2(string currentValue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.Text = currentValue;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }

}
```